# Datatype query on datetime and tinyint

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Mysql datetime column, what should be the corresponding datatype in a java entity bean class for this column?

What would the java-type be for a Mysql tinyint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- For datetime java.sql.Date
- for tinyint byte

[here](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/mapping-mysql-data-types-in-java.shtml) is the mapping table